# JQuery Validation Plugin: Use remote with delay

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I am using the [remote method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) from the [jQuery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) which makes an ajax call. The remote function is activated each time a key is pressed in the input field. I would like to add a delay, so that the ajax request is only trigged when the user stopped pressing a key for some miliseconds.

This problem was posed in 2012 [at GitHub](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/466) but was closed by the developer in 2015:

> I'm sorry for the lack of activity on this issue. Instead of leaving
>   it open any longer, I decided to close old issues without trying to
>   address them, to longer give the false impression that it will get
>   addressed eventually.

In the discussion forum, the user lohfu proposed the following solution:

```
$.validator.methods._remote = $.validator.methods.remote;

var timer = 0;
$.validator.methods.remote = function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);

    var args = arguments;

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $.validator.methods._remote.apply(this, args);
    }.bind(this), 500);

    return "pending";
};
```

However, there are two main problems:

1. It does not work. If I add the delay and the remote function returns false, then the form gets still submitted.
2. When I enter something in the input filed which causes an error by the remote function it correctly gets `class="error"` assigned. If I now select a different input, the `class="error"` switches to `class="valid"`, although the error message is still present and the error message is still shown. The same happens when I press submit.

---

Here is a minimal example:

HTML

```
<form action="test.php" method= "POST" id="form">
    Name:  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Email:  <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JS

```
    $("#form").validate({
     rules: {
       name: "required",
       email: {
         required: true,
         email: true,
         remote: {
           url: "ajax.php",
           type: "post"
         }
       }
     },
     messages: {
       email: {
         remote: "Email already exists"
       }
     }
   });
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$valid = null;

echo json_encode($valid);
```

This form should never be submitted, because the ajax.php always returns false. However, entering a name and a valid email will submit the form, despite the fact that the error "Email already exists" is shown.

Comment: Instead of responding with the string 'null', could you try using string 'false'?

Comment: @Dr.Flink If I would return the string 'false' instead of null then it will be used as the default error message. So I get the error message "false" instead of "Email aready exists".

Answer (score 0):

Does the following fiddle work as expected?
You can change the url into true or false instead:

```
url: '/echo/js/?js=[null|true|false]',
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ww0zh9jm/2/

..you have to ad the external resources (Fiddle removes them):
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I enter something in the field 'name' and a valid email in the field email then I can submit the form, even though I see the error message "Email already exists". BTW: I dont need to include external resources, they are saved correclty as external + you dont need to include jquery as external source, you can click the javascript button and select jquery there.

Comment: This is really awkward. It definitaly worked for me when I posted it, but now it's totally broken (sometimes the validator doesn't even seem to be registered). Do you have to use this specifik validation plugin?